# get the serverside control id in javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have asp:ImageButton in asp:table.
I want to get the id of button in javascript and I want to enabled the button based on conditon. How cloud I acheive.
I tried as below.

```
var btn;
btn = document.getElementById('<%= generateRptbtn.ClientID%>').value;
btn.enabled = true;
```

But I'm getting empty as btn value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use value.

```
 var btn = document.getElementById('<%= generateRptbtn.ClientID%>');
 btn.disabled = false;
```

This way you get the actual button object.  Value would return the contents of the value property of the html input element rendered by the asp button

Also I believe in javascript you would set disabled to false rather than enabled to true

Comment: But but still not enabled why? I set enable="false" default

Comment: The enabled property for the asp.net server control is different.  When the control is rendered on the page it is an html input of type submit.  It's javascript and dom properties are independent.

Comment: How can I set the imageurl there for that button?

Comment: Since button is a server control you can do ImageUrl="~/yourpathhere" server controls can resolve paths and the ~ identifies the application root.

Comment: function checkDates() {
          var start = $find('<%= begnDate.ClientID %>').get_selectedDate();
          var end = $find('<%= endDate.ClientID %>').get_selectedDate();
          var btn = document.getElementById('<%= generateRptbtn.ClientID%>');
          if (start && end) {
              btn.disabled = false;
          }
          else 
          {
              btn.disabled = true;
              btn.ImageUrl="~/images/disablebtn.gif";
              }

      } this is how I'm doing

Comment: You are changing the image based on some condition?  What is the condition.  Clicked?  If the button posts back you can change it in your code behind.

Comment: Yes. while page load I need to set the image for button if the two dates are selected. suppose while page load its will contain redcolor image , after user selected dates then we need to set the green color image for button.

Comment: btn.style.background = "url('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("")%>')"; may work in your javascript function.

Comment: btn.style.background = "url('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/disablebtn.gif")%>')"; I did like this but not working..

Comment: Hi latr I tried like this. btn.src = '~/images/disablebtn.gif'; . image is changing but path is getting problem

Answer (score 4):

Check out this article. There are 2-3 ways to get ID of a control in a javascript

http://codedotnets.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-get-id-server-control-javascript.html

and one more thing once you disable the control, its not possible to get the ID or value of that control. So do button.disable = false ;

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution on MSDN site. I think this way is pretty easy and "clean". I use it in asp.net 4.0, I'm not sure, if it works in lower versions.

If you set Button's property ClientIDMode to "Static" in your aspx code like this

```
<asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" runat="Server" ID="generateRptbtn" />
```

then in your .js code you can just call

```
var btn = document.getElementById('generateRptbtn');
btn.disabled = false;
```

And as mentioned **latr0dectus**, you can't call

```
var btn = document.getElementById('generateRptbtn').value;
```

Here's a link to the MSDN site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410598(v=vs.100).aspx .